# application getting crash when reload tabledata

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, ios9

i am making app which have a tableviw and when first time api called table showing data perfectly but when secondtime i open slide out menu and click on button api is calling again and its getting crash on line self.tableView.reloadData().
here is my code in MainViewController

```
 func web()
{
    let url = "http://\(urlString)\(slug)"
    print(url)
    print(slug)
    request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (response:Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in
        if (response.result.value != nil)
        {
            print(response.result.value)
            self.arraypost.removeAllObjects()
            print(self.arraypost)
            self.arraypost = (response.result.value)?.valueForKey("posts") as! NSMutableArray
            print(self.arraypost)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })


        }
    }
}
```

here is mycode in RightViewController

```
@IBAction func btnmotogp(sender: AnyObject) {
    slug = motogp
   MainViewController().web()

    self.slideMenuController()?.closeRight()


}
```

just stuck in this problem and wasted too much time on this.

this is the code for tableview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arraypost.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : mainviewcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainviewcell") as! mainviewcell
    let dic : NSDictionary = arraypost.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    cell.lbldate.text = dic["date"] as? String
    cell.lblsummary.text = dic["excerpt"] as? String
    cell.lbltitle.text = dic["title"] as? String

    let myarray : NSMutableArray = (dic["attachments"] as? NSMutableArray)!
    print(myarray)
    let dic1 : NSDictionary = myarray.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
    print(dic1)
    var newimage : String = ""


    newimage = dic1["url"] as! String
    print(newimage)
    if (newimage.characters.count != 0)
    {
        ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(newimage) { (images, url) -> () in

            if (images != nil)
            {
                cell.image1.image = images!
            }

        }
    }


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SubContentsViewController", bundle: nil)
    let subContentsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SubContentsViewController") as! SubContentsViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subContentsVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: its a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value@Paulw11

Comment: You are force unwarping something with `!`, dont, use `if let...`, and shouldnt call function from different controller, make a delegate to ask the `MainViewController` to do it, maybe your `tableView` did not have the proper data source yet but u call update it anyway

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to find out what is where and how exactly you uses it but my guess is that when you call `MainViewController().web()` the MainViewController's view is not in the views hierarchy so tableView is neither. This provides us to the case when you are calling table to reload but it is not instantiated so it crashes. Make sure that view controller is added correctly.

It would be also nice if you could care about possible retain cycles that blocks can create :)